# Populate data in WPF Telerik Richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I really messed up to populate data in WPF Telerik RadRichtextbox, I'm getting dataset from WCF service named as "LetterServiceClient" and now want to populate data in "Mailing"-->"Insert merge field" dropdown, but failed to do so. For your reference i also attached a screen shot to give you a clear look. [image: WPF-telerik RichTextbox]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<telerik:RadRibbonDropDownButton 
         x:Name="ddinsert" 
         Content="" 
         CollapseToMedium="WhenGroupIsMedium" 
         LargeImage="pack://application:,,,/Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI;component/Images/MSOffice/32/InsertMergeField.png"            
         telerik:RadRichTextBoxRibbonUI.RichTextCommand="{Binding InsertMergeFieldEmptyCommand}" 
         Size="Large" 
         Text="Insert Merge Field" 
         telerik:ScreenTip.Title="Insert Merge Field" 
         />
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
    private void bindData()
    {
        ServiceReference1.LetterServiceClient letterservice = new ServiceReference1.LetterServiceClient();
        DataSet ds = letterservice.ExecuteTagSchema("SearchPatient");
        List<string> listTemp = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn item in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            listTemp.Add(item.ColumnName);
        }

        this.ddinsert.DataContext = listTemp.ToArray();

        //this.radRichTextBox.Document.MailMergeDataSource.ItemsSource = listTemp.ToArray();
        //this.radRichTextBox.Document.MailMergeDataSource.ItemsSource= listTemp.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Problem Solved:  this.radRichTextBox.Document.MailMergeDataSource.ItemsSource = ds1.Tables[0].DefaultView;